# List the factors of an integer

Tags: java

```
  public int[] factors(int n) {
    int count[] = new int[n];
    for (int i = 1; i <= count.length; i++) {
      count[i] = (count.length % i);
      }
      return count;
      }
    }
```

Anyone have an idea how to list all the factors?

Comment: what does your factors method do? Isn't that the answer to your question?

Comment: One suggestion : Array Index starts from `0`.

Comment: I think he did like this because you can't divide by 0.

Comment: @lateralus What does division by zero have to do with the posted code?

Comment: when i = 0 doesn't count.length % i raise an exception?

Comment: @lateralus No, it just returns 0.

Comment: class prova{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(3 % 0);
    }
 }
raises exception to me!

Comment: @lateralus You know what, you're right. I must have never started my loops (when using modulus) at zero either!

Answer (score 1):

- set `int i = 0;` as array starts from `0`
- Factor can only be considered if `value % i==0` so add if condition
- You need one more variable to increment array Index as you can't use `i` for that.So add one more variable to increment array index to add factor.
- Think more on your code, debug especially if possible,check out the values ,add print statements if needed to see what's going on and that's it you will definitely win the task.
- Other than that if you can use `SOF` you can use `Google` as well :)

Comment: +1 for giving the hints to the op

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `List` instead of `array`. Since you can't initialize the array without knowing the size.

Then you can try something like following

```
public List<Integer> factors(int n) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); // initialize the list
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) { // decide the factor.
            list.add(i); // now i is a factor, needs to add to list
        }
    }
    return list; // return list contains factors.
}
```